# Graphical tooltips in Emacs not working as expected

Tags: tooltip

I am trying to make graphical tooltips appear over some words in Emacs. Here is the code I have developed:

```
(defun image-tooltip (window object position)
  (save-excursion
    (goto-char position)
    (let* ((img-file (format "%s.png" (thing-at-point 'word)))
       (s (propertize "Look in the minbuffer"
              'display (create-image (expand-file-name img-file)))))
      (message "%s" s))))

(font-lock-add-keywords
 nil
 '(("\\<kiwi\\>\\|\\<grapes\\>\\|strawberry" 0 '(face font-lock-keyword-face
                              help-echo image-tooltip))))
```

The kiwi.png and other images are stored on disk, and they work fine (you can see it here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uX_hAPb9NOc)
It works fine to put an image in the minibuffer, but the tooltip itself just says Look in minibuffer, and I thought it would instead show the image. Am I missing something in here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should return the propertized string in your `image-tooltip` code:

```
(defun image-tooltip (window object position)
  (save-excursion
    (goto-char position)
    (let ((img-file (format "%s.png" (thing-at-point 'word))))
       (propertize "Look in the minbuffer"
              'display (create-image (expand-file-name img-file))))))
```

The code works fine in my Emacs(version 24.5, Arch Linux).

Comment: hm. I tried that with Emacs 24.1 and 25.1 on MacOSX, and it doesn't work , although in the minibuffer it does work with the image. Interestingly enough, it works on Windows with Emacs 24.5.  I guess it is a Mac thing then. Thanks!

Comment: This does look like a platform specific problem. In Linux, image tooltip is only shown when disabling the system tooltip by `(setq x-gtk-use-system-tooltips nil)`, though I believe in OSX it should be something different. BTW, `dired+` can show image tooltips when the mouse moves over an image name, which looks like something similar to what you want to achieve.

Comment: I was looking at dired+ when I wrote this example ;) unfortunately it also doesn't show tooltips in OSX. I guess this has to do with gtk support on osx. Thanks for the tip though.

Comment: It turns out if I rebuild Emacs with gtk3 support, the image tooltips work! I had previously used  a cocoa option to brew to install it.

Comment: Great! Good to hear your problem is solved!